# What's the difference between stlportd.5.2.dll and stlportstld.5.2.dll?

Tags: c++, stl, stlport

After I compiled [STLport](http://www.stlport.org/), I have obtained three .dll in the bin direcotry: one is for release (stlport.5.2.dll), and the others are for debug (stlportd.5.2.dll and stlportstld.5.2.dll). I was wondering why there are two debug dlls there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stlportstld*.dll` is for the [Debug Mode of STLport](http://www.stlport.org/doc/debug_mode.html):

> Debug mode lets you find very obscure bugs in application code which uses STL iterators and algorithms.
>
> It performs runtime checking of iterator validity and ownership and algorithm preconditions.
>   When debug check reveals the bug, it terminates the program with detailed diagnostics.
>
> STLport in debug mode is as much exception-safe and thread-safe as in release mode.

`stlportd*.dll` is the debug version of `stlport*.dll`, which doesn't provide additional debugging facilities as `stlportstld*.dll` does (although it also can be "debugged").

You can also refer to `stl\config\_auto_link.h` in the STLport package to see the difference among the binaries:

```
#  if defined (_STLP_DEBUG)
#    define _STLP_LIB_OPTIM_MODE "stld"
#  elif defined (_DEBUG)
#    define _STLP_LIB_OPTIM_MODE "d"
#  else
#    define _STLP_LIB_OPTIM_MODE ""
#  endif
```